College-aged kid sent away for some kind of identity theft
This has been making me crazy! I've been thinking about this movie that I saw in the last 5-7 years that, I'm pretty sure, begins with a young guy being sent away from home because he got involved in some kind of cheating scandal or something at school. I don't remember where, exactly, he is sent to, but I feel like most of the film is set in England, though it may just be Europe in general.
One of the main scenes took place in the house of an older man who has befriended the main character, and I seem to remember a group of his older gay friends coming over, though I don't entirely remember if the main character was gay or not. However, even as I write, I do now remember that he had some kind of stolen identity issue throughout the movie, and that there was an important scene toward the end where a boy chastised him for stealing his identity.
Does anyone know what film this is?

Did it also look like a recent movie? English? Hollywood?

Now, this is a story all 'bout how my life got twisted up-side down. In Philadelphia, born and raised, on the playground, spending most of my days...

It sounds like "The Talented Mr Ripley" with Matt Damon.  I've only seen part of it, but here is what I remember.
Matt Damon's character, Tom Ripley, is playing the piano at a posh function.  He is wearing a prestigious college jacket of a friend of his, who was supposed to play the piano that day but broke his hand.  Because Tom is wearing the jacket, he gets mistaken for being a graduate of that college on that certain year.  
One of the men at the gathering has a son that graduated the same year, and this man asks Ripley to go to Italy and try to convince his wayward son to come back home.
The problem is Tom decides he likes the lifestyle this son has set up for himself.  So he starts trying to take over the sons life (possibly trying to kill the son, I didn't get that far).
